# ElasticSearch - Fuzzy match, exact words, any order

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm looking for a search which fuzzy matches the exact phrase in any order. I've read through the docs and cant see anything which can achieve this.

example

If I have a field with `'The quick brown fox'` then these search terms should  match:-

```
The quick brown fox
The brown quick fox
The br0wn quick fox
```

but not

```
The black quick fox
The quick fox
The brown quick fox jumped
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm using ElasticSearch v5.

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you can modelise your problem better for example, why you accept `The brown quick fox`but not `The brown quick fox jumped`. Will you accept: `The brown quick foxs`

Comment: @mel `The brown quick foxs` would be ok as the `foxs` is a fuzzy match to `fox`. `jumped` though is not a fuzzy match to any word.